# update table with field boolean requirement from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables

table1

```
id   kode(boolean)
-----------------
1    false
2    false
3    true
```

table2

```
id   num
1    499
2    390
3    500
```

result :
table1

```
id   kode(boolean)
------------------
1    True
2    True
3    True
```

I want update table1 kode=true when `table2.num < 500`

How can this be done for Postgres

Comment: SQL Server does not have a boolean data type so your question does not make sense.

Comment: please for postgres...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a update-join like below. Though not sure if it's `SQL Server` or `Postgres` since as commented `SQL Server` don't have `boolean` type rather it's `bit` field.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.kode = true
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.num < 500;
```

Here is Postgres syntax:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 
SET kode = true
FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.num < 500;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes true and didn't included that since was not sure about it. Now since OP has confirmed it please see edit in answer.

Comment: thanks for Rahul, but the condition num<500 is needed, please for postgre

Comment: @TedyArian, sorry .. silly me missed that. Please see edit again.